# Outlook Addin Not Loading on Windows xp

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-2007

I have created an Outlook 2007 addin using Visual Studio 2010 and deploy it using click once.Whenever I install the deployed exe in my local system, it works fine.When I am trying to install in an user's machine, the Add-in gets installed but doesn't loaded.It was moved to "Inactive Applications". I have installed another sample application and that's also not working. I have set  VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS to 0 in environment variables. But that's also not showing any error message.  It shows "Not Loaded.A Runtime error Occured during the loading of the COM-Add-in" in load behavior.

Is there anything I am doing wrong or need to do in addition to make this work?

Comment: Are you accessing any local files when your add-in loads?  Make sure any files you need are included in the build and you're referencing them in the install directory.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of it is that office 2007 does not support addin to be installed on a per machine install, it must be installed as per user. Try installing it for user only or download Office 2007 SP3, apply per machine install and see if it works! (Machine installation of addin was only supported on Office2010, try checking the SP3 if it will fix the issue)